# JSF custom validator not invoked when submitted input value is null

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I created a custom validator which is not getting called when input is null.

My validator code:

```
@FacesValidator("requiredValidator")
public class RequredValidation implements Validator {

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println("in valid GGGGGGGG");

    }
```

My xhtml page code:

```
<p:message for="urlInput"  />

<p:inputText id="urlInputv" value="#{coverageBean.firstname}" label="URL" maxlength="2" >
    <f:validator validatorId="requiredValidator"></f:validator>
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="urlInputv"  />
<p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{loginBean.validateText}" />
```

Now this is working when I am entering any value in text box, but it is not working when inputtext is null.

The server is using

- Tomcat
- primefaces 3.5
- jsf2.0

Please could anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: Is `<p:message for="urlInput"  />` relevant to the question or is just adding noise?

Comment: it is just add ing noise . ijust want call my validator at even when inputtext is null

Comment: Well, in this case edit the question and remove it.

Answer (score 17):

By default, JSF does not validate an empty submitted value if Bean Validation (JSR303) is not available in the environment. This behavior can be controlled with the context parameter `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS`.

The default value for `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` is `auto`, meaning that empty fields are validated if Bean Validation (JSR303) is available in the class path.

If you want to validate empty fields anyway without Bean Validation, then explicitly set the context parameter in your `web.xml` to `true` like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It must be said that you normally use `required="true"` in case you want to validate an input field as required. You don't need to perform that job in your custom validator then.

```
<p:inputText ... required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter value" />
```

Or, more abstract with `<f:validateRequired>`:

```
<p:inputText ... requiredMessage="Please enter value">
    <f:validateRequired />
</p:inputText>
```

Do note that you can safely use multiple validators on the very same input component.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put :

```
<p:inputText id="urlInputv" required="true"

....
```

required true is used to avoid null value by user.
If you don't want to have a required input, then initialize your value:

```
firstname = ""; //or a default value
```