# validator for input text using the backing bean method not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form with `h:inputText` and have the attribute validator with the backing bean method name as value, example:

```
h:inputText id="poolmanagementinput" validator="#{poolManager.validatePoolManagement}"
```

Now I have method in backing bean named poolManager in following format:

```
public void validatePoolManagement(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component,
            final Object value) {
... }
```

I expected this method to be called in the validation phase in JSF cycle. But to my surprise this method is not being called and validation is not happening. Could anyone point out any missing point or direct me to a soultion.

Note: Just as a side note the input is placed inside a composite:implementation.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Are you implying that it works fine when placed in a completely blank page without any templates/composites? Please present the problem in MCVE format.

Comment: Yup sure. Let me start that. But the strange thing is that 
validator="#{poolManager.validatePoolManagement}" 
don't work, seems its not identifiying the method.  

But if I change it to validator="#{poolManager.}" the framework identifies it and throws parsing exception.  Even if I give wrong name in EL (Example:  validator="#{polMng.}") still I am not getting any errors. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you have forgot add these attributes between body and form like this

```
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <your ui item>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

sorround your UI attribute with them. `<h:form>` has to be parent tag for all JSF UI components that can participate in HTML form submission.

I have encountered same issue and this has resolved issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a old question but answering it for the people who have the same problem.

JSF is not executing the validators if the value is blank.
You need to use required=true for validation blank.

for more reference [JSF custom validator not invoked when submitted input value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963442/jsf-custom-validator-not-invoked-when-submitted-input-value-is-null)